# Antenna Attenuation, Gain and RSSI calculation

Tags: antenna, transmission-line, coax, best-practice, lora

I am using a RAK7258 LoRa gateway operating at EU-868MHz. I am looking to have the gateway and the antenna on each side of a wall (gateway inside, antenna outside) and receive some packets from some sensors I have outside.
I would need about 1m to 1.5m (3.2ft. to 4.8ft.) cable between RAK and Antenna. I tried calculating the gain and getting an RSSI value and would love some advice; Be pointed in the right direction :)

I did the calculations with 1.5m to estimate a worse case scenario.

Thanks a lot, I really appreciate the help. I have just updated my calculations, from some values for attenuation in small coax cables I found on Table 1 on the data-alliance site [U.FL Cables Coax Types Compared: 1.13mm, 1.32mm, 1.37mm, RG174, RG178](https://www.data-alliance.net/blog/ufl-cables-coax-types-compared-113mm-132mm-137mm-rg174-rg178/).

[image: Signal loss calculation]

Any suggestions on cables or extenders would really be welcome. The RAK uses UFL connector and my outdoor 9 dBi antenna has an N type Female connector. I wouldn't mind terminating the cables myself.

Comment: Haven't you multiplied by 1,5 /len twice?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In the second line where I take the product of 1.5 and 3.2808 is me trying to convert 1.5 dB/ft. to dB/meter (to match the units). I might be wrong here.

The data-alliance link says: 
1.37mm coax attenuation dB/ft
900=1.5

Comment: I agree with Arcatus.  In line 2, you already have the loss for your 1.5m coax.  Why multiply that by the length (1.5m) again?

Comment: Appreciate it, man! I tried looking for the extra multiplication of length as both you guys mentioned. Maybe I'm just blind or stupid or both, but I can't see it hehe. After doing some more research, I have tried updating the calculations with some other values, and just clarifying my approach a bit more.